# async function never executed why in c# with quartz task backgrounder in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, quartz-scheduler

I have a function as you can see here :

```
public class News
{

    public async Task<List<NewsContent>> parsing(string newsArchive)
    {
        List<NewsContent> lstResult=new List<NewsContent>();
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(newsArchive);
        String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
        source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
        HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
        resultat.LoadHtml(source);

        List<HtmlNode> toftitle = resultat.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
          (x => (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("news_list"))).ToList();
        var li = toftitle[0].Descendants().Where
          (x => (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value=="news_item")).ToList();

        foreach (var item in li)
        {
            NewsContent newsContent = new NewsContent();
            newsContent.Url = item.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("href", null);
            newsContent.Img = item.Descendants("img").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
            newsContent.Title = item.Descendants("h2").ToList()[0].InnerText;

            //finding main news content
            var response1 = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://www.nsfund.ir/news" + newsContent.Url);
            String source1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response1, 0, response1.Length - 1);
            source1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source1);
            HtmlDocument resultat1 = new HtmlDocument();
            resultat1.LoadHtml(source1);
            newsContent.Content = resultat1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='news_content_container']").InnerText;
        }
        return lstResult;
    }
}
```

This function just works like a robot to get the news from a website and return that as you can see above .

In my project i use a nuget called `quartz` to run a schedule every minute to run this function to update the news.

```
public class JobBackground : IJob
{

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        News newagent = new News();
        Task<List<NewsContent>> lst = newagent.parsing("http://www.nsfund.ir");

        List<NewsContent> enresult = lst.Result;

    }
}
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobBackground>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

As you can see every minute this schedule calls my function to update the news.but the problem is the result never returned .

I put a `breakpoint`  in this line in scheude

```
List<NewsContent> enresult = lst.Result;
```

but never this line executed .why ?I put the schedule in this line

```
Task<List<NewsContent>> lst = newagent.parsing("http://www.nsfund.ir");
```

And it executed .

Comment: The duplicate marker is plain wrong. The problem isn't that - although it is really bad - he accesses the Result directly but that his linq for toftitle returns an empty result set. And that's because the source of this website doesn't contain "news_list".

Comment: @ManuelZelenka how you know the newslist is empty ?

Comment: @ManuelZelenka do you have any ideas ?

Comment: 1) I executed your parsing method and I got an ArgumentOutOfRangeException on the next line due to the fact that you access toftitle like so: `toftitle[0]`
2) I looked at the source code of the homepage you posted and there is no string in it called news_list

Comment: I guess what you are actually looking for is latest-news

Comment: Or you access the wrong page. On http://www.nsfund.ir/news there is actually the news_list found

Comment: @ManuelZelenka the nsfund.ir/news is the correct page

Comment: @ManuelZelenka i don't have any errors to fetch the page

Comment: @ManuelZelenka can i use a simple method without any async method ?

Comment: Well if your code still blocks with the correct page then the duplicate marker is correct. Please refer to Stephen Clearys blog post: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: before lst.result can i use this : Task.WaitAll(lst);

Comment: @ManuelZelenka you are right the main problem was news_list,my URL was wrong .thank you